# Client-side API requests not caching using fetch in Next JS

Tags: javascript, caching, next.js, fetch-api

I am using Next JS to build an app that fetches data from an external API. Given that the data received from the API will be relatively static, I am using [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache) to store the data for 24 hours and re-use when the user refreshes the page. This has been working great when called in `getStaticProps()` as shown below:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const value = cache.get(urls);
  if (value) {
    return {
      props: {
        result: value,
      },
    }
  } else {
    const data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => 
      fetch(url, options).then(resp => resp.json())
    ));
    cache.put(urls, data, 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60);
    return {
      props: {
        result: data,
      },
    }
  }
```

However, as part of the `urls` that are called they require an `&timezone=` parameter. I am detecting the users timezone using the code `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` but given that `getStaticProps()` is server-side, it is not able to correctly include the script in the API call so the timezone parameter is being ignored.

I have tried to fix this by switching the API call to be client-side using the code below:

```
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  
  async function getData() {
    const cached = cache.get(urls);
    if (cached) {
      setResults(cached);
    } else {
      const data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => 
        fetch(url, options).then(resp => resp.json())
      ));
      cache.put(urls, data, 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60);

      setResults(data);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

The timezone parameter is now calling correctly but the cache appears to have stopped working. Each time I refresh the page it re-fetches the data from the API rather than using the cached result.

Can cache be stored in this way using client-side data fetching or do I need to use a different approach?

Comment: All memory of javascript is cleared when reloaded. You can use `localStorage` but I would rather suggest going back to server-side fetching

Comment: Thanks @Konrad - I would prefer to switch back to server-side fetching but how would I then be able to detect and pass the user's timezone (eg. 'Europe/London') to the API call?

Comment: I would create an endpoint and fetch the endpoint from the client, then the endpoint will do exactly the same thing as `getStatisProps` did before

Comment: @Konrad Thanks! I've set up an API route in `pages/api/events` with a code that returns either `res.status(200).json(cached)` or `res.status(200).json(data)` depending on the cache status. Then I'm fetching it on the client-side using the `getData()` function with a query parameter of `?timezone=${timezone}` - Is that what you meant? Thanks very much.